# Quick shell (bash+awk) script to extract a column using the output of another command

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk

Have to repeat below 100+ times. So first command takes paramater `$1` and get me string `A001C7F28AB20`. Then second command is using that string.

```
 # Command1 ->snmpget -v1 -c elephantblue $1 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0
SNMPv2-MIB::sysName.0 = STRING: A001C7F28AB20     
 # Command2 ->LSMcli server user password Show -F=nibtp | grep A001C7F28AB20
A001C7F28AB20 0.0.7.227 x.y.z.w "VPN-1 Express/Pro ROBO" Standard_Office_1100
```

How should I extract the `x.y.z.w` with a given `$1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
LSMcli server user password Show -F=nibtp | grep $(snmpget -v1 -c elephantblue $1 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0 | awk '{print $4}') | awk '{print $3}'
```

Comment: The duplicated `snmpget` looks like a typo in the question.

Comment: The `elephantbluesnmpget` is the community string fort he device, the `snmpget` is a command.

Comment: Actually, you're right - it does look like a copy/paste error...

Comment: Please use $(), not backtics. That way you don't have to escape something when you assign the result: `xyzw=$(LSMcli server user password Show -F=nibtp | grep $(snmpget -v1 -c elephantblue $1 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0 | awk '{print $4}') | awk '{print $3}')`